# c++ trailing return declaration but no 'auto'

Tags: c++, templates

I happened to come across [this syntax](https://godbolt.org/z/oY2FBl) from Kris Jusiak:

```cpp
template<class... Ts> struct overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overload(Ts...) -> overload<Ts...>;
```

At first I thought it was trailing return-type syntax, but I expected to see 'auto' before 'overload'.  Could someone kindly direct me to the cppreference page which I am guilty for not knowing?

Thanks much!  Sincerely, George

Comment: look like : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction